# Avoid overlapping shapes in Visio

Tags: vba, shapes, overlap, visio

I recorded a macro to add custom shapes from stencils and assigned to command button.

When adding shapes multiple times, the shapes are adding on top of existing shapes that I added previously. Is there any way to stop that happening?

```vb
Sub Circle ()
Dim DiagramServices As Integer. 
DiagramSevices=ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled. 
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140 + visServiceVersion150. 
ActiveDocument.Windows.ItemEx("Test").Activate. 
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop Application.Documents.Item("Custom.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Circle"),9,7. 
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices. 
End Sub.
```

Comment: Please add tag `vba` and your code in your previous question for prevent closing this thread.

Comment: You can add behavior `Move shapes on drop`, watch [this gif](https://surrogate-tm.github.io/gifs/remove.gif). But this offset is unmanaged!!!

Comment: Added the code can u suggest what to do.

Comment: Code recorded via **Macro Recorder** ! Do you want always drop `Circle` at same position (9,7) ? What should happen if there is already a below-next shape under the dropped shape?

Comment: I want to drop next shape on next free position available like if shape is in position (9,7) I want to drop next shape in (9,9) automatically so on.

Answer (score 0):

@Fallen, please try this code

```
Sub ForFallen()
' determine variable for spatially related shapes
Dim vsoReturnedSelection As Visio.Selection
' define the shape
Dim sh As Shape
' determine variable coordinates of the shape
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
' assign initial coordinates of the shape
x = 7
y = 9
' drop shape to the point with initial coordinates
Set sh = ActivePage.Drop(Application.Documents.Item("Custom.vssx").Masters.ItemU("Circle"), x, y)
' get the set of spatially related shapes for dropped shape position
Set rel = sh.SpatialNeighbors(visSpatialOverlap, 0.25, 0)
' if shape overlapped other shapes start next loop
If rel.Count > 0 Then
' this loop is repeated until there are no overlapped shapes left under the shape
Do
' increment X-position for 2 inches
x = x + 2
' move shape to new position
sh.SetCenter x, y
' obtaining a set of spatially related shapes for a new location of shape
Set rel = sh.SpatialNeighbors(visSpatialOverlap, 0.25, 0)
Loop While rel.Count > 0
End If
End Sub
```

Read more about [SpatialNeighbors property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.spatialneighbors) and [SetCenter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.setcenter)…

Comment: Thx Surrogate Worked like charm